# Spring Boot cannot config database connection down to zero

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-rds, hikaricp, aws-aurora-serverless

I am deploying my Spring Boot REST API on AWS Fargate, which connects to AWS Aurora Postgresql Serverless V1.

I have configured the Aurora to scale the ACU to 0 when idle as in the following picture, so that I am not charge too much when I don't use the API.

[image]

Initially, my Spring Boot App maintains 10 idle connections by default, so I have tried to make it zero by adding the this to `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=0
```

And then I see from AWS console that the database connection has been reduced. But it remains 1 connection forever.

[image]

Please help suggest if you know how to make it zero.

The Spring Boot database configuration is basically like this

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

## Edit 1

I used the suggestion in the comment to check if the connection really comes from Spring Boot.

It turns out there is no active connection but `/actuator/metrics/hikaricp.connections.idle` always return the value of 1

```
{"name":"hikaricp.connections.idle","description":"Idle connections","baseUnit":null,"measurements":[{"statistic":"VALUE","value":1.0}],"availableTags":[{"tag":"pool","values":["HikariPool-1"]}]}
```

And it seems does not relate to health check because I have tried running it locally and the result of `/actuator/metrics/hikaricp.connections.idle` remains 1.

I set `logging.level.root = trace` to see what is happening.

There are only 2 things keep printing in the log periodically

1. The Hikari connection report, showing 1 idle connection

```
{"level":"DEBUG","ref":"|","marker":"INTERNAL","message":"HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","timestamp":"2022-06-14 16:15:16.799","thread":"HikariPool-1 housekeeper"}
{"level":"DEBUG","ref":"|","marker":"INTERNAL","message":"HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","timestamp":"2022-06-14 16:15:16.800","thread":"HikariPool-1 housekeeper"}
{"level":"DEBUG","ref":"|","marker":"INTERNAL","message":"HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","timestamp":"2022-06-14 16:15:16.800","thread":"HikariPool-1 housekeeper"}
```

2. Tomcat NioEndpoint, but I think it is not relevant

```
{"level":"DEBUG","ref":"|","marker":"INTERNAL","message":"timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1655198117181; nextExpiration=1655198117180; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false","logger":"org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint","timestamp":"2022-06-14 16:15:17.181","thread":"http-nio-8445-Poller"}
```

Comment: Is it certain that connection is established by the application? It might be good idea to ensure no connection within AWS infrastructure.

Comment: Maybe healthchecks keep connection up?
You can also query actuator endpoints to check, if those are spring-boot connections, for example `/actuator/metrics/hikaricp.connections.active`

Comment: If that is your configuration you can remove it (as it will actually not bind all the properties like this) and is more or less the default in Spring Boot. Also depending on which version of Spring Boot you are using there is no `spring.datasource.minimumIdle` property but you should use `spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=0`

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your suggestion, I have investigated further as per your suggestion and update what I found in the post. It seems the connection really comes from Spring but it is an idle connection and not from health check.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yep, I was confused by the properties at first as you point out. But I have tested that the property is effective, because of the explicit binding in `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")`. If I remove `spring.datasource.minimumIdle` the connection will become 10

Comment: Because you used the wrong property, so remove it and use the correct property. That being set, idle doesn't mean core size of the pool, which for HikariCP seems to be hardcoded to 1. Which kind of makes sense why would you else use a connection pool.

Comment: Forget the core size I mentioned, I was mixing connections and thread pools in the code. Nonetheless you have metrics enabled and for the health check a connection is used, so it might be that one (although it should be closed afterwards). Do you mess around with connections yourself?

Comment: Hi all, my bad, you guys are completely right, it is because the health check. I can make it zero now by setting `management.health.db.enabled=false`, thank you so much

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer, not as an inline edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion in the comment, this is because of the actuator health check, which can be solved by the following settings

```
management.health.db.enabled=false
```